# Difference between giving pandas a python iterable vs a pd.Series for column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iterable

What are some of the differences between passing a `List` vs a `pd.Series` type to create a new dataFrame column? For example, from trial-and-error I've noticed:

```
# (1d) We can also give it a Series, which is quite similar to giving it a List
df['cost1'] = pd.Series([random.choice([1.99,2.99,3.99]) for i in range(len(df))])
df['cost2'] =           [random.choice([1.99,2.99,3.99]) for i in range(len(df))]
df['cost3'] = pd.Series([1,2,3]) # <== will pad length with `NaN`
df['cost4'] =           [1,2,3]  # <== this one will fail because not the same size
d
```

Are there any other reasons that `pd.Series` differs from passing a standard python list?  Can a dataframe take any python iterable or are there restrictions on what can be passed to it? Finally, is using `pd.Series` the 'correct' way to add columns, or can it be used interchangably with other types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List` assign to dataframe here require the same length

For the `pd.Series` assign , it will use the index as key to match original `DataFrame` `index`, then fill the value with the same index in `Series`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=[9,8,7])
df['New']=pd.Series([1,2,3])
 # the default index is range index , which is from 0 to n 
 # since the dataframe index dose not match the series, then will return NaN 
df
Out[88]: 
   0  New
9  1  NaN
8  2  NaN
7  3  NaN
```

---

Different length with matched index

```
df['New']=pd.Series([1,2],index=[9,8])
df
Out[90]: 
   0  New
9  1  1.0
8  2  2.0
7  3  NaN
```

Comment: why wouldn't it default to a RangeIndex and leave fill the remainder with np.nan? perhaps showing a warning... anyone knows if this is being considered?

Comment: @BEN_YO -- ok, but what about the other components of the question (anything other than NaN fill-down)

Comment: @samuelbrody1249s Check my first example , Since the index different, it will assign NaN, the first match for pandas object assign is matching the index